# Deployment of webapp using Weblogic.deployer on a weblogic cluster

Tags: jenkins, weblogic, pipeline

I am trying to deploy a webapp sample.war file to a weblogic cluster (12C) which is running on a docker based environment but I am getting the below error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [properties/ssl/ssl.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist.
```

Below is the command I am using:
    docker exec -it wlsadmin /u01/oracle/deploy.sh CHGXXXX weblogic weblogic1!

Below is my deploy.sh code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
CHANGE=$1
WL_USER=$2
WL_PASS=$3
source ~/.bash_profile
WL_PATH="/u01/oracle"
TARGET=DockerCluster
cd $WL_PATH/$CHANGE
for FILE in `find *.war`
do
java -cp $CLASSPATH weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://XXXX:XXXX -username 
$WL_USER - password $WL_PASS -deploy $FILE -targets DockerCluster
done
```

Comment: When it starts, your application is looking for a file ssl.properties under properties/ssl but can't find it. Install thie file and redeploy your application. This is not w wls issue.

Comment: Even I got the same from the error, do you by any chance know the exact location of this file in WL domain and contents of the file as I am not even able to find the directory where it should reside. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your code if this file is loaded from the classpath or directly from the file system.

Comment: Thanks you very much, it solved my issue! seems like I was using a war file which was expected to use ssl connection.